# Difficulty aliasing `is_x?` to `has_role? x`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, method-missing

Each user has many roles; to find out whether a user has the "admin" role, we can use the `has_role?` method:

`some_user.has_role?('admin')`

Which is defined like this:

```
def has_role?(role_in_question)
  roles.map(&:name).include?(role_in_question.to_s)
end
```

I'd like to be able to write `some_user.has_role?('admin')` as `some_user.is_admin?`, so I did:

```
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    if method.to_s.match(/^is_(\w+)[?]$/)
      has_role? $1
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

This works fine for the `some_user.is_admin?` case, but fails when I try to call it on a user referenced in another association:

```
>> Annotation.first.created_by.is_admin?
NoMethodError: undefined method `is_admin?' for "KKadue":User
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.4/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:215:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):345
    from :0
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails checks if you `respond_to? "is_admin?"` before doing a `send`.

So you need to specialize `respond_to?` also like:

```
def respond_to?(method, include_private=false)
  super || method.to_s.match(/^is_(\w+)[?]$/)
end
```

*Note*: Don't ask me *why* rails checks for `respond_to?` instead of just doing a `send` there, I don't see a good reason.

*Also*: The best way (Ruby 1.9.2+) is to define [`respond_to_missing?`](http://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_method.c#L1288) instead, and you can be compatible with all versions with something a bit fancy like:

```
def respond_to_missing?(method, include_private=false)
  method.to_s.match(/^is_(\w+)[?]$/)
end

unless 42.respond_to?(:respond_to_missing?) # needed for Ruby before 1.9.2:
  def respond_to?(method, include_private=false)
    super || respond_to_missing?(method, include_private)
  end
end
```

Comment: To elaborate, you'd need to override `respond_to?` as well to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

The `ActiveRecord::Associations::AssociationProxy` class overrides `method_missing` and intercepts the call you are looking for before it gets to the model.

This happens because AP checks if the model `respond_to?` the method, which in your case, it doesn't.

You have a few solutions aside from editing Rails' source:

First, manually define each of the is_* methods for the user object using metaprogramming. Something like:

```
class User
  Role.all.each do |role|
    define_method "is_#{role.name}?" do
      has_role?(role.name)
    end
  end
end
```

Another is to load the User object via some other means such as

```
User.find(Annotation.first.user_id).is_admin?
```

Or use one of the other answers listed.